# How to use a if statement in XML

Tags: xml

I have the following code:

```
If dr("dlat").ToString <> "0.000000" Then
                        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("mapped")
                        XmlWriter.WriteString("Yes")
                        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
                    Else
                        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("mapped")
                        XmlWriter.WriteString("No")
                        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
                    End If
```

I wanted to know how could I use the Yes or no part. 
The reason is `IF mapped = yes` then add address in xml, If no then dont write address.

```
   XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("address")
    XmlWriter.WriteCData(dr("sStreetNumber") & " " & dr("sStreetName"))
    XmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If dr("dlat").ToString <> "0.000000" Then
                        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("mapped")
                        XmlWriter.WriteString("Yes")
                        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("address")
                        XmlWriter.WriteCData(dr("sStreetNumber") & " " & dr("sStreetName"))
                        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
                    Else
                        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("mapped")
                        XmlWriter.WriteString("No")
                        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
                    End If
```

This should be working just fine right ?